# Odds of getting a certain amount of lottery numbers correct?

Tags: probability, statistics

If Stacey buys a lottery ticket where she picks 4 numbers, and then 4 balls from a pit of balls labeled 1-20 are drawn (there are only 20 balls, i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4 .. 20) what are the odds she will get 2 out of 4 of the numbers correct?

My answer is as follows: (Using 4 choose 2 / (20 * 19 * 18 * 17)

$\frac{\binom{4}{2}}{20 * 19 * 18 * 17}$

However, this doesn't feel correct.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 2):

You will want to use the hypergeometric distribution:

$$ \frac{ \binom{4}{2} \binom{16}{2} } { \binom{20}{4} }$$

We start by choosing two out of the four winning balls. We then choose two losing balls from the remaining sixteen balls. We divide this by the number of ways to choose four balls.